# magnifyWithEvent: only called when app is activated

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsresponder

My `NSViewController` implements `magnifyWithEvent:`. The window is a `NSPanel` with `NSNonactivatingPanelMask` as a `styleMask` flag.

Because of that, opening the window and using it will not activate the NSApplication. This means that the old window will not become unfocused. This is the desired behaviour.

Unfortunately, `magnifyWithEvent:` is only called when the application is activated. Why is this? How can I receive `magnifyWithEvent:` calls without having to activate the application?

Comment: Seeing the same issue. I think it's a recent change with 10.9 or 10.10. Have you figured out a solution?